# automatic height dimensions of the table view cell is not working properly

Tags: uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am building the chat app in which I am using the automatic dimensions of table view for cells but height for cell is not working properly for some cells.

[image]

and here is the constraints of view [image]

here is the screen shot of view hierarchy
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set contentcompressionresistance(vertical) to 1000  and contenthuggingpriority (vertical) to 1000

Comment: @RanaAsad have you set automatic dimension true and estimated height for tableview?

Comment: I also set that in viewDidLoad

Comment: please check the view hierarchy of that cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the `greaterThanOrEqualTo` constraint for the label height

Comment: no luck first time view height is ok but when I scroll the table view then it shows issue in height and I am finding the solution from one month but no luck

Comment: can you check now??